# RethinkDb changefeeds not working when including `.pluck`

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a changefeed that works fine until I use the `pluck()` projection.  If I use pluck, it doesn't pick up changes form inserts and deletes in my followers embedded collection.

```
 r.table('users')
    .getAll(name, {index: 'followers'})
    //.without('password', 'phone')
    .pluck('name', 'online') // using pluck doesn't pick up changes in insert/delete from followers
    .changes({includeInitial:true});
```

I could use the `without` command but that seems more error prone as I would have to keep updating that list anytime I added fields to the user object.

Updates to user's online property gets picked up in the changefeed in either scenario.

Why does pluck not show changes to the followers set/collection property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is because when you add the `.pluck('name', 'online')` to the end, and then you update the `followers` array, the changefeed logic applies the pluck and then compares the old value to the new value, and since neither of the plucked fields changed it decides that it's a "trivial" change and drops it.  (In general ignoring trivial changes is what you want, since one of the main goals of `.pluck.changes` is to only be notified when the specified fields change.)

I think this probably isn't the desired behavior, though: it's probably more useful to only drop trivial changes if they don't cause the row to enter or exit the subscribed range.  I opened https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5205 to track that change.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported right now. Check [this](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4267) ticket and [this](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3623).

Comment: Those issues refer to getting changes on transformations of *point* changefeeds, like `.get.pluck.changes`, which is unsupported.  `.get_all.pluck.changes` should be supported, since the `get_all` makes it a range changefeed.